# Avoid background color in image c#

Tags: image-processing, colors, uwp, background-color

I have a image processing in my uwp app where i read the colors of the image and display the results based on the matching colors.
To read the colors i use [Color theif](https://github.com/KSemenenko/ColorThief) and get the color palette.

The problem is at times the background color is considered as the primary color since it is dominent

[image]

In the above image the second color must be the primary color of the image which i need. But the gray is obtained as primary color.

Comment: The gray is obtained as primary because it is the *predominant* color in the image. You need to tweak the algorithm to ignore the greyish color or you may consider changing the background color to white (since the algorithm is already capable of ignoring it)

Comment: changing the bg color to white? Can it be done during image processing or u mean the image itself must be of white background

Comment: Both can be done..Would be easier if you have images with white background..Also,if you are having images having the exact same background color, then you can either change them to white or tweak the existing logic to ignore it (via code)..

Comment: I Cant say images will be of white or exact same color. There is a case where i process camera images too.

Answer (score 0):

Since image background could be of any color, I think the best bet is to pick colors from the corners of an image (which more likely to be of background color) and compare them against the colors of the palette returned by `ColorThief` using the [Color difference formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).
You could then use color differences and the amounts of times the color from `ColorThief` palette was a match to corner pixel color as weight coefficients to decide which one of the `ColorThief` palette colors is more likely to be the background color of the image.